# shopping cart rule for freeshipping not working with subtotal

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping, price-rules

Could any one please help me to set up a shopping cart rule for freeshipping in magento for  all orders over **AED - 1,850, USD - 500, GBP - 350, EUR -  450**. I tried to set the option **Subtotal  equals or greater than** but its not working.

Comment: is your store default currency is USD or what?

Comment: Please refer this link - http://www.phpro.be/news/configuring-shopping-cart-price-rules-magento-free-shipping

Comment: This is how I created the rule, but it`s not working